# Every Group of Order 9 has an element of order 3

Tags: group-theory

Prove that every group of order 9 has an element of order 3.

So my attempt at this proof was:

Pf. Let $G$ be a group of order 9.
Then $\exists H$ such that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H|$ $\vert$  $|G|$.
Thus $|H|= $ 1,3, or 9 by Lagrange's Theorem.

I know this proof is not complete, but I am unsure on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there… each element of G has an order which divides 9 so the order of each $g\in G$ is 1,3 or 9.

case 1: $ord(g) = 1$, then it's the neutral
because there can only be 1 of it, the other 8. need to be case 2 or 3

case 2:  $ord(g) = 3$, you are done

case 3: $ord(g) = 9$, consider $g^3$ which has order 3

Comment: Slightly embarrassed because it was so obvious.  Thank you!